# Fourier transform of the operator $\log^2(-\Delta)u$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, logarithms, fourier-transform, laplacian

I need to calculate the Fourier transform of the operator $\log^2(-\Delta)u $, but I don't know any property that can help me. I know that the transform of $\log(-\Delta)u $ is $\log(|\xi|^2)\hat{u}(t)$. Something tells me the transformation I want is $\log^2(|\xi|^2)\hat{u}(t)$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: How do you know the statement about $\log(-\Delta)$? How is that case different from $\log^2$? Honestly, I take the multiplication by $f(|\xi|^2)$ of $\hat u$ as a definition for $f(-\Delta)u$, so you should specify what is your definition of $\log^2(-\Delta)$.

Comment: In general, you should write more details about what you already know, the exact definition of the objects you write, as it is difficult to answer questions with few details. If you do not know what is the definition of an object you mention, you should make that clear in a math forum, as calculate and define are two different things

Comment: See [THIS ANSWWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188070/logarithm-of-differential-operator/2188409#2188409).