# What is the natural logarithm of d/dx?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, derivatives, operator-theory

What is $\ln\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)f(x)$?

If $e^{\frac{d}{dx}}f(x)=f(x+1)$ is the shift operator, and we can conclude that using the taylor expansion of the exponential function, how would we evaluate $\ln(\frac{d}{dx})f(x)$?

Comment: We can only do the equivalent of $\ln D$ where $D$ is a linear operator if $D$ is "close to" $1,$ because that is where the power series for $\ln$ converges. $d/dx$ is probably not close enough to $1,$ so a power series approach won't work. The power series of $e^D$ on the other can, works fine, at least where $f$ is analytic at $0$ with radius of convergence $>1.$

Comment: I would guess: if $\phi(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ is a Maclaurin series, then we define the operator $\phi(\frac{d}{dx})$ as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (\frac{d}{dx})^n$.  But $\ln$ is not analytic at $0$, so it has no Maclaurin series.  Hence, you will need some other definition for $\ln(\frac{d}{dx})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an appropriate domain in the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb R)$, the derivative operator $D$ is a normal operator, unitarily equivalent under the Fourier transform to multiplication by $-ix$.
Choosing a particular branch of the logarithm, we can then define $\log(D)$ using the functional calculus.  The result is equivalent under the Fourier transform to multiplication by $\log(-ix)$.

Comment: Thanks, so is this what you're saying? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188070/logarithm-of-differential-operator?rq=1

Comment: Yes, that's it.